# Cannot push .net MAUI app to iPhone from Windows Computer - ApplicationVerificationFailed

Tags: ios, .net, visual-studio-2022, maui

Up until this week I have been using Xamarin.Forms for my mobile development.  I got a request for a simple app and I thought I would take this opportunity to use .net MAUI.  Things were going fine and I tried the app on Windows, on Android and then attempted to try it on iPhone.  I cannot get Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0 Preview 2.0 to install the app on the iPhone.

I have a paid Apple Developer account and I can install and run my Xamarin.Forms apps on an iPhone just fine.  For my Xamarin.Forms app I use Automatic Provisioning for bundle signing.

I can't even get the blank .net MAUI app to install on the iPhone.  I tried the default values of Bundle Signing (Scheme = Manual, Signing Identity = Developer (automatic)).  I have tried Automatic Provisioning (configuring Automatic Provisioning game me a green check mark).  Every time I push that little green play button I get ApplicationVerificationFailed (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found).

Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0 Preview 2.0 on Windows 11 64-bit.
iPhone 11 Pro Max - software version 15.5 (plugged directly into the Windows machine)

Did .net MAUI devolve from Xamarin.Forms in this capability or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you transfer the project to a mac, test from VS 2022 mac? Also, I don't know if it is related, but *Apple* removed support for Automatic Provisioning uploads to TestFlight. (Try to upload an update to an X-Forms app that uses Automatic Provisioning; that will fail now too.) Perhaps this also interferes with Automatic Provisioning to test devices, if the appropriate provisioning profile isn't already cached on the Mac. Anyway, try the (annoying) Manual Provisioning steps instead.

Comment: I do not have a mac, but I know someone who does and do plan on getting them involved.  I will try the manual route, but that may not happen for a while.  Apple is sending me to the poor house, one gifted case of beer at a time.

I am using the same IDE for my Xamarin.Forms app that successfully installs on the same iPhone device.  So there is gotta be something different between Xamarin and MAUI.

Comment: *"... something different between Xamarin and MAUI". Yes. Multiple differences: switch to .Net 6, multi-targetting from a single project, and /or the new Minimal Hosting app startup mechanism. Apple's dropping of support for Automatic Provisioning complicates matters. Perhaps VS has some residual support re XF that still works, but that does not help Maui. Are you following steps in [Provision Maui for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/provision)? [PITA to have to go back to such manual steps, but its beyond MS' control apparently.]

Comment: I did look at that link but pretty much checked out at the beginning when it said "On your Mac".  With the Xamarin making such a big deal a couple of years ago on how you can use Hot Restart to install an iOS app without a Mac, it would be a nice courtesy to come out and say "Sorry, but we can no longer do this".  Just to stop myself from wondering what am I doing wrong.  I do plan on going the manual route but I am at the mercy of another person for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One step closer is better than not...

Thanks To Alexander, I was able to at least install the app on an iPhone (app doesn't work but at least it installed and I was able to launch it).

The work around can be found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-Community-2022-64-bit---Preview-Ver/10076777#T-ND10096812).

Basically, I copied the Entitlements.plist file from my working Xamarin.Forms iOS app and pasted it under Platforms/iOS folder in my MAUI project (and removed some keys within the file).

Thanks Steve and Alexander for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is currently being `tracked` in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/:-0xe8008015-A-valid-provisioning-profi/10073337?space=8&q=hotrestart&sort=newest).

Please follow up with [that thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/:-0xe8008015-A-valid-provisioning-profi/10073337?space=8&q=hotrestart&sort=newest) closely as our team will provide an update if either more information is needed, a workaround is available, or the issue is resolved.

Fortunately, per this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-Community-2022-64-bit---Preview-Ver/10076777#T-ND10096812), the `workaround` is that we can add a new `entitlements file` to your .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) app project, and add a new XML file named Entitlements.plist to the `Platforms\iOS\` folder of your app project. Then add the following XML to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I will watch that thread closely.  To me, the reason I was sold on Xamarin was the ability to not only have one code base (with minor device specific pieces of logic) **AND** **AND** **AND** the ability to install on those devices.  So much that I committed to paying Apple's ridiculous $99 a year Developer subscription.